# sm-msp-queue says: unable to qualify my own domain name (xxx) -- using short name

Tags: cron, syslog, hostname, sendmail

Every 20 minutes, for days, `sm-msp-queue` (something related to `sendmail`, I guess) writes a message in my `ubun` that goes like that:

> unable to qualify my own domain name (ubun) -- using short name

where `ubun` is the network node hostname (output of `uname -n` and contents of `/etc/hostname`).

The contents of `/etc/mail/local-host-names` include two lines: `localhost` and `ubun`.

The file `/etc/hosts` begins with two lines:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 ubun
```

The file `/etc/cron.d/sendmail` contains one cronjob that is set to run every 20 minutes:

```
*/20 *    *    *    *   smmsp test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp
```

However, I don't know what the command `smmsp` should do; I can't run it alone, also with `sudo` (I get `sudo: smmsp: command not found`). Running `sudo /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp` seems to be doing nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have a fully qualified domain name for your server, this message should go away.
In `/etc/hosts`, you can define a FQDN like `ubun.somedomain.tld` :

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 ubun.example.com ubun
```

To apply the new host name without rebooting the system type (after having changed the `/etc/hosts` file) :

```
$ sudo hostname ubun.example.com
```

Then check you have the FQDN :

```
$ hostname -f
```

`smmsp` at the place you show it (in `/etc/cron.d/sendmail` is not the command name but the username to use to run the command that follows. The rest of the line is the command (testing if `sendmail` is present and executable and then run it with a specific option for executing actions to do in crontab).

If run at the terminal the command seems to do nothing (print nothing on the screen) this doesn't mean that she doesn't do something.

By the way, this command is run at regular interval to do the submission of mails waiting in the queues of Sendmail. So if you disable it, mails will never be delivered.

Comment: And what if you don't have an FQDN?

Comment: @KenSharp make one up - it just has to meet FQDN criteria